# How can I check if the direction of the rotation is not 0 and not the same as the last one?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Not sure if I did it right in the random part that the next direction will not be 0 and not the same.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class rotate : MonoBehaviour {

    public Vector3 Direction;
    [Range(0,300)]
    public float speed = 10f;
    public bool randomSpeed = false;
    [Range(0.0f, 360.0f)]
    public float angleToRotate = 360.0f;
    public bool randomDirection = false;

    private Quaternion lastRotation;
    private Vector3 lastDirection;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        lastRotation = transform.rotation;
        lastDirection = Direction;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (randomSpeed)
        {
            speed = Random.Range(0, 300);
        }

        if (randomDirection)
        {
            Direction = new Vector3(Random.Range(-1, 1), Random.Range(-1, 1), Random.Range(-1, 1));

            if (Direction == new Vector3(0, 0, 0) || lastDirection == Direction)
            {
                Direction = new Vector3(Random.Range(-1, 1), Random.Range(-1, 1), Random.Range(-1, 1));
            }

            lastDirection = Direction;
            randomDirection = false;
        }

        transform.Rotate(Direction, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

This part:

```
 if (randomDirection)
            {
                Direction = new Vector3(Random.Range(-1, 1), Random.Range(-1, 1), Random.Range(-1, 1));

                if (Direction == new Vector3(0, 0, 0) || lastDirection == Direction)
                {
                    Direction = new Vector3(Random.Range(-1, 1), Random.Range(-1, 1), Random.Range(-1, 1));
                }

                lastDirection = Direction;
                randomDirection = false;
            }
```

I want that the direction will never be 0,0,0 and also not the same as the current one. So the each time the next direction will be different.

Update:

This is what I'm doing now. (Not tested yet)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class rotate : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Vector3 Direction;
    [Range(0, 300)]
    public float speed = 10f;
    public bool randomSpeed = false;
    [Range(0.0f, 360.0f)]
    public float angleToRotate = 360.0f;
    public bool randomDirection = false;

    private int counter = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (randomSpeed)
        {
            speed = Random.Range(0, 300);
        }

        RandomDirection();

        transform.Rotate(Direction, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private void RandomDirection()
    {
        if (randomDirection)
        {
            Direction = new Vector3(Random.Range(-1, 1), Random.Range(-1, 1), Random.Range(-1, 1));
            while (Direction == new Vector3(0, 0, 0))
            {
                counter++;
                Direction = new Vector3(Random.Range(-1, 1), Random.Range(-1, 1), Random.Range(-1, 1));

                if (counter == 5)
                {
                    Direction = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
                    break;
                }
            }

            counter = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

In the RandomDirection method inside the while if the result is 0,0,0 and it's 5 times in row then I give a default direction and stop the loop.

Comment: Well, your current version would only check once. If the second random (in that if) would actually give the same result, as unlikely that is, it would take it. You'd have to put a loop (while) there.

Comment: Because `Random.range()` returns a float, it is entirely (statistically) impossible for the random vector to be identical to the previous direction. Also, if the directions *are* the same, you generate a new vector, but you never validate *that* vector as being not-same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the current direction is equal to (0,0,0) or the previous direction. You can run the direction through this `ChangeToSlightlyDifferentVector3(Vector3 vector3)` method I have written below.

It will offset each coordinate in the vector3 by either adding 1 or subtracting one, but keeping it within the boundaries of -1 to 1. Whether or not it adds or subtracts one is random, but as it will either add 1 for all or subtract one for all, and as it checks for (-1, -1, -1) and (1, 1, 1), it cannot end up as (0,0,0) or the previous direction.

```
Vector3 ChangeToSlightlyDifferentVector3(Vector3 vector3){
    int RandomChance = Random.Range(0,100);
    if (vector3.x == 1f && vector3.x == 1f && vector3.x == 1f)
    {    //Has to "add or loop" so it doesn't end at 0.
        RandomChance = 100f
    }
    else if (vector3.x == -1f && vector3.x == -1f && vector3.x == -1f)
    {    //Has to "subtract or loop" so it doesn't end at 0.
        RandomChance = 0f;
    }
    float x = RandomizeToDifferentOne(vector3.x, RandomChance);
    float y = RandomizeToDifferentOne(vector3.y, RandomChance);
    float z = RandomizeToDifferentOne(vector3.z, RandomChance);
    Vector3 newVector3 = new Vector3(x,y,z);    
    return newVector3;
}

float RandomizeToDifferentOne(int input, int RandomizeChance){

    if (RandomChance < 50)
    {
      return DeductOrLoop(input);
    }
    else
    {
      return AddOrLoop(input);
    }
}

float AddOrLoop(float input){
    float offset = Random.Range(0.1f, 0.75f);
    float leftOver = (input + offset) - 1f;
    input += offset;
    if (input > 1f)
    {
    input = -1f + leftOver;
    }

    return input;
}

float DeductOrLoop(float input){
    float offset = Random.Range(0.1f, 0.75f);
    float leftOver = (input - offset) + 1f;
    input -= offset;
    if (input < -1f)
    {
    input = 1f;
    input -= leftOver;
    }
    return input;
}
```

Comment: `Random.Range` returns a *float* between the two values, so this code does not have the same range of results as the asker's. Also, your code is 100% deterministic. You never make a call to a random number anywhere.

Comment: My code only offsets the values by +1 or -1. But it does ensure that the number will not be 0,0,0 nor the previous one.

As for Random.Range it can both return a float and an int. But you are right that I should have returned a float value as that would fit OPs example. Will change that.

The "random" part of mine is that it will already have been through a random generator once as per OPs code and thus is just slightly offsetted from the random.

Comment: I added a randomizer effect which will make it more random, to the add/deduct methods.

Comment: Your (original) code is equivalent to `(if x == 1) x = -1 else x = 1` for all 3 components.

Comment: It is now more random.

The reason I use 0.75f instead of 1f now is to avoid that it ends up going to e.g. -1 and then having added +1 to end up at 0. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: and actually it was not "(if x == 1) x = -1 else x = 1", only for some cases.

For example, if the vector had been -1, 0, 1, then it could have ended up both subtracting or adding. Which would have been done to all 3 meaning that it would have become (0, 1, -1) or (1, -1, 0).

Comment: Point. I still don't think its a good idea to use the same random (the up/down one) for all 3 portions of the vector, however.

Comment: That is also something they no longer do :-). Due to the new random offset + possible leftover float values. Or do you mean that they should not all subract or all add?

Comment: No no, this rand: `int RandomChance = Random.Range(0,100);` Also,it may still be possible for the result to end up as `(0,0,0)`. Checking...

Comment: True. Suppose one could add or deduct a random value if they should end up at (0,0,0), which would not allow the x, y and z to be set to the previous values either.

Comment: That's why a better solution is `while(dir == zero || dir == last) { dir = new Random() }`

Comment: Definitely shorter. For some reason I don't like the infinitely small chance  that it will loop endlessly. I think I'd rather have a for-loop going up to 100 times.

Comment: It's already statistically impossible for a random float between -1 and 1 to ever equal the previous value. You're right that the *possibility* is there, but its so insignificant as to be zero. If the possibility is at least statistically insignificant, I apply a maximum-number-of-loops conditional. As that probability is virtually nil, it would also be advisable to use [Mathf.Approximately](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html) to compare floats.

Comment: @Doh09 There was some errors in your code so I fixed them all but I;m not sure about this part: I had to change all the three int's to floats and add to each one (int) and change from vector3 to Vector3: float x = RandomizeToDifferentOne((int)Vector3.x, RandomChance);
        float y = RandomizeToDifferentOne((int)Vector3.y, RandomChance);
        float z = RandomizeToDifferentOne((int)Vector3.z, RandomChance); I'm not sure if this is the right way to fix it. But now there are no errors.

Comment: vector3 is a reference to the input. Vector3 vector3.

It is however correct that those should be floats and not ints. Forgot to change them. So what you write inside the parameter depends what you call the Vector3 input.

Comment: @BenziAvrumi, I recommend you read the discussion that Draco18s and I had. It might be just as useful to just run Random.Range a few times.

Comment: @Doh09 Updated my question with what I'm doing now. Using a while to check for 0,0,0 do you think it's logic and good enough ? I didn't add yet the random directions repeat check. But the idea and code as I did it is fine ?

Comment: @Doh09 And how can I make it using this while also to check for the random -1,1 ranges ? I need to store the last and current direction ?